# API GET request through unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unitywebrequest

I have followed two different tutorial on how to get API requests with headers through Unity.
One uses WWWForm and the other uses UnityWebRequest. I want to send my API-key through headers, it works with WWWForm, but I want to use UnityWebRequest instead.

The one with WWWForm(WWW class)

```
public class API: MonoBehaviour
{
    private const string url = "http://localhost/admin/activecodes";
    public const string API_KEY = "XXXXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX";
    public Text responseText;

    public void Request()
    {   var www = UnityWebRequest.Get(url);
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();

        Dictionary<string, string> headers = form.headers;
        headers["x-access-token"] = API_KEY;

        WWW request = new WWW(url, null, headers);
        // UnityWebRequest www = new UnityWebRequest(URL);
        StartCoroutine(OnResponse(request));
    }

    private IEnumerator OnResponse(WWW req)
    {
        yield return req;
        responseText.text = req.text;
        // responseText.text = req.downloadHandler.text;
    }
}
```

The one with UnityWebRequest:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class API : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text responseText;
    public async void TestGet()
    {
        var url = "http://localhost/admin/activecodes";
        var API_KEY = "XXXXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX";

        Dictionary<string, string> headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        headers["x-access-token"] = API_KEY;


        using var www = UnityWebRequest.Get(url);
        
        www.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", headers.ToString());
        www.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

        var operation = www.SendWebRequest();

        while (!operation.isDone)
        {
            await Task.Yield();
        }

        var jsonResponse = www.downloadHandler.text;

        if (www.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
        {
            Debug.LogError($"Failed: {www.error}");
        }

        try
        {
            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ValidCodes>>(jsonResponse);
            Debug.Log($"Success: {www.downloadHandler.text}");
            foreach (var code in result)
            {
                responseText.text = code.activecode.ToString();
            }
            // return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.LogError($"{this} Could not parse response {jsonResponse}. {ex.Message}");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `headers.ToString()` cannot possibly be correct. Forget the dictionary, try just setting a `x-access-token` header

Comment: @Crowcoder Yes ```headers.ToString()``` does not work, I tried setting a  ```x-access-token ``` header. I get an error "wrong or no access token"

Comment: Unrelated, but just FYI - your api key is not safe if it is stored on the device. If having that key exposed would be a problem for you then you need a different architecture.

Answer (score 0):

One mistake I can see is

```
www.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", headers.ToString());
```

headers is a Dictionary and `ToString()` won't give you the result you are expecting, you need to pass key as well to get the value `headers["x-access-token"]` will return your `API_KEY`.

However I don't see the point of using Dictionary here, you could just use your `API_KEY` directly like following.

```
www.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", API_KEY);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first snippet makes little sense tbh. You are somehow mixing `UnityWebRequest` and (the obsolete) `WWW` and create a `WWWForm` that is nowhere used.

---

In the second snippet `headers.ToString()` will just return

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]
```

[`SetRequestHeader`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.SetRequestHeader.html) is indeed the equivalent for the items in the `Dictionary<string,string>` for the `WWW`.

So I think instead of introducing the new key `"Authorization"` you rather simply want to set this header with the same key and value as in the dictionary:

```
www.SetRequestHeader("x-access-token", API_KEY);
```

---

In general also you should check the result **before** you try and access the text like

```
if (www.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
{
    Debug.LogError($"Failed: {www.error}");
    return;
}

var jsonResponse = www.downloadHandler.text;
```